# Why do new and object.create behave differently in this example

Tags: javascript, function, object, methods

In this simple example, why do `new` and `Object.create` behave differently?

```
var test=function(name){
    this.name=name
};
var test1= new test("AAA");
test1.name;//AAA

var test2=Object.create(test);
test2.name="AAA";
typeof(test2);//Object
test2.name;//"" (empty string).
```

Why is `test2.name` empty?

Comment: I can't reproduce. Where are you running this?

Comment: in firefox, using firebug console

Comment: You should be passing `test.prototype` to `Object.create`.

Comment: @CrazyTrain: it worked using test.prototype, would you mind giving a bit of explanation on that?

Comment: @user1988876: It's because JavaScript inheritance isn't really based on constructor functions. It's a simple object to object relationship. So when you invoke a constructor like `new test()`, what you're really doing is creating a new object that inherits from the object at `test.prototype`. Therefore the equivalent using `Object.create` is to pass `test.prototype` since that's the object you're inheriting from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) expects an *Object* as it's first argument for the prototype chain, not a *function* (or constructor in your case).

It won't complain if you pass a *function*, but it means that certain extra things will be inherited by your created *Object*, for example, the non-writability of function names.

The reason you're getting an empty string is because `test` is an anonymous function, so `test.name` is `""`. As I said above, this is non-writable, so

```
test.name = 'foo';
test.name; // still ""
```

If you had used a named *function expression* for `test`, this would have been more obvious.

```
var test = function foobar() {},
    ex = Object.create(test);
ex.name; // "foobar"
```

---

**EDIT** a function that behaves like `new` for `test` using `Object.create` would look like this

```
function myNew() {
    var o = Object.create(test.prototype); // set up prototype inheritance
    test.apply(o, arguments);              // then construct
    return o;
}
// and using it
var test3 = myNew('AAA');
test3.name; // "AAA"
test3.name = 'BBB';
test3.name; // "BBB"
```

This pattern is not guaranteed to work with DOM constructors.

Comment: I do not want the name of function. I want the parameter passed to the foobar. ie      var test=function foobar(name){
this.name=name};
var test2=Object.create(test);
test2("ddd"); test2.name//ddd but this not working again

Comment: @user1988876 As I said, the `.name` property of a _function_ is _non-writable_, and this _non-writability_ is being _inherited_ by `test2`.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to change the .name property when I created object using `new` keyword, but when created using `Object.create`, this property becomes non-writable correct? in that case, what argument should I pass to `Object.create` to make it work like `new`. or how would i access test.name by creating object using `Object.create`. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The word "name" is "almost reserved" in JavaScript. If you try a normal attribute name, it should work. For example,

```
var test=function(name){this.name=name};
var test1= new test("AAA");
test1.name;//AAA
var test2=Object.create(test);
test2.name2="AAA";
typeof(test2);//Object
console.log(test2.name2);//"AAA"
```

For difference between the two ways of creating objects, [this page](http://www.theoryapp.com/javascript-inheritance-pseudoclassical-vs-prototypal/) shows some examples with explanation.

Comment: isnt that weird. it works with the object created using `new`, but not with the one created using `Object.create'..