# Prototype concept as given in Mozilla docs

Tags: javascript

I was reading the JavaScript Object Model as given in Mozilla documents (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Details_of_the_Object_Model) and have what might be a very silly question.

As you can see, it describes a prototype-based inheritance hierarchy (Manager inherits from Employee) as the following:

```
function Employee() {
  this.name = "";
  this.dept = "general";
}

function Manager() {
  Employee.call(this);
  this.reports = [];
}

Manager.prototype = Object.create(Employee.prototype);
```

Shouldn't the last line say `Employee` instead of `Employee.prototype`? I think it should be the former if we're going to build a prototype chain. Please explain.

Comment: Because [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) expects a prototype as the first parameter.

Comment: @Passerby In that case, do `name` and `dept` automatically get added to `Employee.prototype`? If not, I'm wondering how do they become accessible to `Manager`? Does the `Object.create()` function magically descend down the prototype chain and figure out which properties were added?

Comment: IMO `name` and `dept` in this case does not below to `Employee.prototype`, they are just two properties attached to each `Employee` _instance_. `Manager` _instances_ get these two properties too, via the `Employee.call(this)` "construction" process.

Comment: @Passerby Very interesting observation! Yes, I had completely forgotten about the `call()` method.

Comment: Also, [`name` is a property in `Function`'s prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name), which may explain why `name` is missing in @VladZ. 's case #2.

Comment: @Passerby I'm not sure I understand that fully, but I think your other comments helped answer my question. `Function` or `Manager` in this case is not a prototype object, but a constructor, and so we need to pass a prototype. While it does clash with my learning that everything in JS is an object, I think with more time I'll come to understand it fully. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because `Object.create` expects a prototype as the first parameter. You can find all the specifications at the following [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create).

I also went on and tested the case that you suggested and it displayed an interesting behavior.

**Case #1**

```
function Employee() {
  this.name = "";
  this.dept = "general";
}

function Manager() {
  Employee.call(this);
  this.reports = [];
}

Manager.prototype = Object.create(Employee.prototype);
```

If we create a new Manager(), we get the following:

```
var x = new Manager();
console.log(x);
```

**Console Output**: *Manager {name: "", dept: "general", reports: Array[0]}*

If we change the code as per your suggestion and pass Employee as a parameter instead of Employee.prototype:

**Case #2**

```
function Employee() {
  this.name = "";
  this.dept = "general";
}

function Manager() {
  Employee.call(this);
  this.reports = [];
}

Manager.prototype = Object.create(Employee);
```

If we now go on and create a Manager, the newly created object will not contain the `name` property like in **Case #1**:

```
var y = new Manager();
console.log(y);
```

**Console Output**: *Manager {dept: "general", reports: Array[0]}*

**EDIT #1**

I did a bit more research and found another question on Stackoverflow ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17245580/why-do-new-and-object-create-behave-differently-in-this-example)) that might explain this behavior.

It appears that it has something to do with the way constructor functions behave.

As it is stated in the aforementioned thread, when you create an object  using the new operator, you basically create a new object that inherits from that object's prototype.

Therefore, since JavaScript inheritance is object to object, it makes sense to pass the prototype as the blueprint from which you want your new object to inherit from.

Comment: Thanks. I can see how the behavior differs, but I still think the docs don't make the case clear enough. Here's what the link you provided has to say about the parameter passed to `Object.create`: _The object which should be the prototype of the newly-created object_. Now,as I see it, we want `Employee` to be the prototype of `Manager`. `Employee.prototype`, as I see it, doesn't even have the name and dept properties. How then, do these get inherited? I don't suppose there's a difference between normal objects and prototype objects . . .

Comment: @dotslash: I did a bit more research and found some additional information here on Stackoverflow. Please check out EDIT #1. Hope it helps!

Comment: @dotslash One of the difference is, `Employee` is a `Function` object (object of prototype "Function") (consider it a "class"/"constructor"), while `Employee.prototype` is just a plain object, "describing" the structure of `Employee`.